# JPQL ORDER BY from calculated field / expression

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sql-order-by, expression, jpql

This is a follow-up question to [JPA/JPQL: AS identifier disallowed in SELECT clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807738/jpa-jpql-as-identifier-disallowed-in-select-clause) basically.

Here's the JPQL query:

```
  SELECT NEW com.domain.project.view.StandingsStatLine(
      ro.id
    , cl.name
    , te.ordinalNbr + 1
    , pa.wasWithdrawn
    , SUM(CASE WHEN paf.wasWithdrawn = FALSE AND paa.wasWithdrawn = FALSE AND scf.finalScore IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       // g = games
    , SUM(CASE WHEN paf.wasWithdrawn = FALSE AND paa.wasWithdrawn = FALSE AND scf.finalScore > sca.finalScore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  // w = wins
    , SUM(CASE WHEN paf.wasWithdrawn = FALSE AND paa.wasWithdrawn = FALSE AND scf.finalScore < sca.finalScore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  // l = losses
    , ...
    , <very complex multi-line expression> // nrp = normalized ranking points
    )
  FROM Club cl
    JOIN cl.teams te
    JOIN te.rosters ro
    JOIN ro.season se
    JOIN ro.participations pa
    JOIN pa.group gr
    JOIN gr.round rd
    JOIN rd.subCompetition sc
    JOIN sc.competition cn
    JOIN gr.games ga
    JOIN ga.scores scf
    JOIN ga.scores sca
    JOIN scf.roster rof
    JOIN sca.roster roa
    JOIN rof.participations paf
    JOIN roa.participations paa
  WHERE ...
  GROUP BY ...
  ORDER BY pa.wasWithdrawn, nrp DESC, w DESC, g DESC, cl.shorthand
```

This is the same statement as in the previous question **without** the `... AS ...` expressions.

For whoever is interested:

1. the nrp are "normalized ranking points". This is a simple percentage of the maximum number of attainable points according to games played. Background is, that a team with 10 games played has a much higher total number of points (there's 1 point awarded per loss) than a team that has played only 6 games. It is THE actual ranking indicator. w and g are explained in code.
2. scf and sca are score for and against (filtered in `WHERE`)

**Q:**

How do you `ORDER BY` such calculated properties in JPQL? I have this quite often, but since the `... AS ...` in a SELECT seems to be invalid JPQL (Hibernate can handle them), how do you generally solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Also see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL_BNF#New_in_JPA_2.0 . Note, the **2nd to last** example there.

```
select_item ::= select_expression [[AS] result_variable]
```

Allows AS option in select.

```
SELECT AVG(e.salary) AS s,
    e.address.city
FROM Employee e
GROUP BY e.address.city
ORDER BY s
```

I have no idea if this is supported in constructor expressions, too, but I see no reason as to why not to do so.